# How to use 'Dropbox API' for streaming video in android?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to make application that can streaming video from dropbox server.

so I use coreAPI and refered documents, tutorial but can't find example about streaming video. only find download picture, upload picture...

So I have no idea that how to start this project! T.T
What I only understand is how to get authentication, but doesn't know how to access my uploaded video, and download or streaming play.

Should I make mediaplayer class? surfaceView?

Is there some example about this?

I really desire want to get some solution.

Comment: Dropbox api don't provide online url so that you can't streaming it

Comment: Hmm...............Really?
I saw that is possible.
If not, Is there any other way to streaming it?

Comment: I am not implement this feature, one way I think that is download video in background first then play... If you have others way to streaming video, please let me know .... thanks

Comment: Aha! Thanks for advise. Could you let me know how to use that way? download background and then play! Could you give me some example?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a media link. See the Core HTTP docs: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media.

Here's the Android call: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#media(java.lang.String, boolean).

That will give you back a temporary URL to the file, which you should be able to pass to whatever video player element you use.

Comment: Thanks! But I refered that before, but I can't use 'media link' in android. TT...How can use that code?

Comment: Why can't you use a media link on Android?

Comment: I'll posting my new question including my code. Would you check that source? I'll attach my new URL soon!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620604/how-to-play-streaming-video-using-dropbox-api
This is my question.