# How to play streaming video using Dropbox API?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, dropbox, dropbox-api

Now I develope application that play video streaming.

My video fild uploaded at dropbox and using Dropbox Core API and media method.

[Media method](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#media%28java.lang.String)  ,
 [Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android)

What I made code is this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();

    mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    checkAppKeySetup();



    btn_con=(Button)findViewById(R.id.con_btn);
    btn_con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mLoggedIn) {
                logOut();
            } else {
                if (USE_OAUTH1) {
                mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(MainActivity.this);
            } else {
                mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this);
            }
        }
    }
    });



    btn_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.movie_btn);
    btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                URLpath =  mDBApi.media("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxxxxx/uprightrow.mp4",false);

            } catch (DropboxException e) {
                Log.d("sibal",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

}

I want to make, 
When I click btn_con, connect with my dropbox (actually, my final purpose will don't make this button. Automatically link)
When I click btn_play, using media method to URL, streaming video.

But when I run my application,
After click btn_con bring this screen,[image: When I click btn_con]
and after click btn_play, nothing happended.
URL path can't recieve anything TT[image: after click btn_play]

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you're calling `media` but passing in a URL instead of a path. (It looks like you essentially already have a media URL.)

Comment: Ah! Thanks smarx! I recognize your answer just before. Hmm! You mean parameter of media method should be 'path' not 'URL'. Then.... What is exactly path means? I can't understand about that.TT
/public/ folders name?

Comment: The path within Dropbox. If you have a file called "hello.txt" in the root of your Dropbox folder, the path would be "/hello.txt". If you move that file into a folder called "test", then it would be "/test/hello.txt".

Comment: Thank you smarx ^.^ you give me such a big help!

Comment: Ah! Hi smarx. I complete all of things by your favor until now, but I have one more question to ask you. I'll attach my URL. If you have time, plz give me one more advise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642752/when-using-dropbox-coreapi-how-to-skip-user-permission

Answer (score -1):

this way can solve your problem for auth finish.
In your onResume()

```
AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();
if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
    try {
        session.finishAuthentication();
        TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
        Log.i("henry","tokens.key = "+ tokens.key);
        Log.i("henry","tokens.secret = "+ tokens.secret);
        // do something with dropbox api
    }
}
```

Dropbox don't provide online url for each file so that you can't play streaming video from dropbox

Comment: Hello henry!
Umm....Then Should I put my code

' URLpath = mDBApi.media("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxxxx/uprightrow.mp4",false); '


would be placed in onResume?

Comment: You need to startAuthentication at first and in onResume to finish auth then get mApi to do dropbox operation, you need to get dropbox object and use it to do file operation.

Comment: protected void onResume()    {         
super.onResume();\nAndroidAuthSession session = mDBApi.getSession();
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                session.finishAuthentication();
                storeAuth(session);
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } catch ~~~~  }

Comment: @henry4343 Yes, Dropbox does provide URLs for any file, via the media method as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @smarx !
Hello! could you check about that? T.T