# When using Dropbox CoreAPI, how to skip user permission?

Tags: android, api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm making an application that plays streaming video through Dropbox. 
My videos are uploaded to a Dropbox public folder. I'm using coreApi, media method, and I have had success getting my video's path and playing it. But whenever I run the application, I see two unexpected screens:

First, if a user doesn't login at dropbox, my application demands a dropbox account login.

Should whoever uses my application, need to have their own account? If so, someone who doesn't have an account, can't use our service? If an user account isn't needed, I want to skip this screen.

Second, after login dropbox account, Dropbox also demands user permission to access the dropbox folder like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYbQx.png), I also want to skip this screen.

Is this possible using Dropbox API?

Comment: The Dropbox API is used to access a user's Dropbox. You can't access a user's Dropbox unless they have an account and authorize your app. It sounds like maybe you don't want to use the API at all? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Ah. Smarx, I want to make an application that provide videos to app user. And just dropbox is used as server and application access to dropbox server, user just get provide video through app!

Comment: Then maybe all you need to do is get the link once from *your* account and use that link in the app? If so, there's no need to use the API. Just share the file and then get the direct link (the one that starts with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`). Note, though, that Dropbox does have bandwidth limits on share links, so make sure your usage isn't going to exceed those limits.